# WPF MVVM: User Control Views not being refreshed on CRUD?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am using WPF in the MVVM pattern. I am using Entity Framework. I have a main window (Entitlements view) with a tab control. The tab items within this view are each bound to a view which are User Controls.

[image]

Entitlements view:

```
  <TabControl Grid.Row="1">
        <TabItem Header="Accounts" Content="{Binding AccountsViewModel}"/>
        <TabItem Header="Users" Content="{Binding UsersViewModel}"/>
    </TabControl>
```

The App.Xaml.cs Instantiates the Entitlements View at initialisation:

```
 public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        var viewModel = new EntitlementsViewModel();
        mainWindow.DataContext = viewModel;
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

The DataContext is set in the View Xaml:

```
 xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DIEntitlements.ViewModels">            
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:AccountsViewModel x:Key="AccountsViewModel"/>
 </UserControl.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource AccountsViewModel}">
```

ViewModel DataTemplates in the App.Xaml:

```
  <ResourceDictionary>           
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AccountsViewModel}">
            <v:AccountsView/>
        </DataTemplate>            
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:UsersViewModel}">
            <v:UsersView/>
        </DataTemplate>            
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

& finally a bit of the ViewModel code:

Property:

```
    private ObservableCollection<tbUsername> _usersCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<tbUsername> UsersCollection
    {
        get { return _usersCollection; }
        set
        {
            _usersCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UsersCollection");
        }
    }
```

Linq Method:

```
  private void GetUserHeaders()
    {
        var query = from u in _context.tbUsernames
                    where u.accountId == SelectedAccountHeader.accountid
                    select u;

        UsersCollection = new ObservableCollection<tbUsername>(query);
    }
```

On first tab selection, the corresponding ViewModel constructor is invoked & the UI displays as intended. The issue comes when a change is persisted back to the database but the UI is not refreshed. I am implementing INotifyPropertyChanged correctly in the View Models. I think this issue is born from only having the 1 instance of the view model and view constructed at initialisation which is then kept in memory & not re-initialised when the change is persisted. Is there a way of refreshing the UI without having a clunky 'Refresh' button' in the UI?

Comment: Although you have provided a lot of info, a nose at the VM would be helpful to complete the picture. I notice you have 'Accounts' (plural). Have you used IEnumerable, or IList instead of something like an observable collection? IEnumerable and IList don't support change notifications. Change notification is the most likely source of error. Also - although it might seem obvious - have you checked for any errors in the output window? Once everything is bound properly, you certainly shouldn't need a refresh button.

Comment: Updated the question @Hockey. Yes I'm using ObservableCollection<T> properties exposed in my ViewModel. Everything is working fine apart from the UI not automatically refreshing without purposefully losing View/ViewModel scope & re-initialising.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. You mean your `UsersViewModel.UserCollection` is changing, and you want this to trigger a redraw of the UsersView? If that's the case, just have your EntitlementsViewModel add a handler to the `UsersViewModel.PropertyChanged` event, and have it raise `OnPropertyChanged("UsersViewModel")` whenever the UsersCollection property changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue after much tinkering.

Here is my RefreshEntities() method which invokes MergeOption.OverwriteChanges; which essentially overwrites the context entity & reloads the collection with the new data from the DB. You're telling EF to overwrite the entity you pass in. I'm invoking this method wherever I'm persisting changes to that view

```
   private void RefreshEntities()
    {
        var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext;
        var objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<vwAccountHeader>();
        objectSet.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
        AccountHeaderCollection = new ObservableCollection<vwAccountHeader>(objectSet);
    }
```

Seems very verbose but works great. I would recommend this for any MVVM WPF app where you are trying to update a view in the UI which has changed by user interaction with an associated table in the EF framework model. Essentially where there's a cross relationship between tables & a view & you need to update that view in the UI.

MergeOption.OverwriteChanges overwrites all pending changes but you can use MergeOption.PreserveChanges to merge reloaded values just to your edited values.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the comments - It looks like you are using the ObservableCollection correctly, but the objects in that collection do not Implement INotifyPropertyChanged as they are straight from the DB.

I would suggest you need another layer, where you convert these 'POCO' objects into a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. You could inherit from [BindableBase](https://github.com/Q42/Q42.WinRT/blob/master/Q42.WinRT.SampleApp/Common/BindableBase.cs) . To create a property using it, a property will look something like this:

```
private int _displayNumber;

public int DisplayNumber
{
  get { return _displayNumber; }
  set { SetProperty(ref _displayNumber, value); }
}
```

If you can't be bothered to do all your conversion, you can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to do the transfer.

So the general flow would be:

1. Get the data as you are doing
2. Convert it into a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged *on each property within the class*.
3. Add to ObservableCollection
4. Bind as you are currently binding

...then reverse for the way back to get it to the DB.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: If you found an answer, please could you post it for the benefit of searchers :)

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're saying about using DTO's. My issue is that the EF context is not refreshed due to the same viewModel & view instance being persisted. I need to dispose & fire a new view but have no idea how to do this!